# Web spider for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads

I'm looking for a web spider for Ubuntu like this one [Webripper - Calluna Software](http://www.calluna-software.com/Webripper). You can download a whole site like you can with

```
wget -r -m example.com
```

but the feature I'm looking for is you can input a search term like "Linux" and it searches the Web and downloads them.
Are there any programs on Ubuntu like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Google Alerts to create a sort of search page delivered to a feed and then use an RSS reader or Thunderbird to read them.

I use Thunderbird for RSS. I don't know if there are any RSS readers who could export the feed to simple html.

Answer (score 9):

Give httrack (CLI) or webhttrack (web interface) a shot, it's in the universe repo. I'm not sure about the search-term-feature you describe, but it does offer a bunch of easily configurable options.

<s>http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/oneiric/webhttrack</s>

[HTTrack Website Copier - Free Software Offline Browser (GNU GPL)](http://www.httrack.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can give [http ripper](http://29a.ch/httpripper/) a try.

Here are some features posted on the website:

> ```
> Free Software (GPL 3)
> Generic (works with almost every website)
> Runs on GNU/Linux and Windows
> Nearly undetectable / blockable by servers
> Built with python and pygtk
> ```

[image: http://29a.ch/httpripper/screenshots/2.png]
<sup>Screen-shot</sup>

Watch a tutorial, from the developer of httpripper himself:

- [httpripper.ogg](http://29a.ch/httpripper/httpripper.ogg).

Download link:

- [httpripper_1.1.1_all.deb](http://29a.ch/httpripper/httpripper_1.1.1_all.deb)

It worked for me under Ubuntu 11.10 x64

Answer (score -1):

There are adequate modules at Perl's CPAN. You just need a little bit of perl scripting.

In particular, take a look at the WWW:Mechanize module at the [WWW:Mechanize module](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.71/).