# How to allow wget to recursively download a whole directory instead of the "index.html" file

Tags: command-line, wget

I want to use wget to download a whole image directory(something like `mystie.com/images/`) from one server to another. But when I go

```
wget --no-parent --recursive http://mysite.com/images/
```

I am always getting a generated `index.html` file instead of the directory. I know I probably need to do something on the source server to allow `wget` to retrieve the contents in it, but I don't know how not even what keywords to search. Thank you for your help.

Both server are running under ubuntu 16.04 and I have root access.

Comment: Here is a related topic that could give you some ideas: [How do I create a CLI Web Spider that uses keywords and filters content?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991447/566421)

Comment: With `wget` you have two possibilities: you can mirror the site over http, as you do, but then you will only get the images that are linked to on the website; or you can do `wget` over FTP by specifying an FTP username and password. In the latter case, `wget` can retrieve a listing of the items in the directory and download them all.

Answer (score 1):

wget can download only what is served by the web-server. If you have a blank index.html in the directory, then wget can only download that file.

An alternative method would be to use sftp like this:

1. `sftp username@server_ip`
2. Enter your password
3. `get -r /var/www/html/images/`
4. `exit`